# How to get a return value from runnable thread and not block with join?

Tags: java, multithreading

How can I get a return value back without using join (since it blocks in this case) or use a class variable to save the result?

Or how can I make this asynchronous wiit java 6/7 and spring 3.2.3?

```
   public String createStuffPublic (final String stuffId) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run() {
            try {
                // long running method to get a string...stored in class variable
                _output = createStuffPrivate(final String stuffId);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
              // err
            }
        } });
        t.start();
        t.join();  // this blocks so really can't use it to get the result
        return _output;
   }

   public void driverSimulatedMultiClientCallMethod() {
       ...
       // no blocking want to execute in parallel
       for (int i=0; i<numClients; i++) {
         String output = singleton.createStuffPublic ("client" + i);
         System.out.println("output for client" + i + ": " + output);    
       }
   }
```

Comment: Can you use a [`Future`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)?

Comment: Or use the observer design pattern.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, possibly but not sure how exactly. pretty new to java threading but just looking at the Future ref.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Share data between java threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106329/share-data-between-java-threads)

Comment: The problem seems to me, how to notify the calling code that something has been calculated, that a new result is ready for use, which is why an observer pattern such as that which can be obtained with PropertyChangeSupport and PropertyChangeListeners, would be useful. The Future would then be used to obtain the result and capture exceptions.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, ok cool, i see where you are going with the observer pattern!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a shared variable like a queue, and synchronize.

[Share data between java threads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22106329/823470)

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaConcurrency/article.html

http://bit.ly/1ko1dOX

http://90kts.com/2007/10/25/sharing-data-safely-between-java-threads/

http://www.journaldev.com/1061/java-synchronization-and-thread-safety-tutorial-with-examples